# How to make sub navbar two to three columns

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, themes, navbar

Hi there I am trying to clone the navbar of cointelegraph.com, however, I'm not good at CSS this is the photo of What I'm trying to accomplish[cointelegraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3ndC.png)

[Protrada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIJh5.png)

the goal is when a user hovers the navbar instead of full dropdown the sub-category will be divided into three.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css grid. This will position the nav items into a three column grid

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Item 1</a>
  <a href="">Item 2</a>
  <a href="">Item 3</a>
  <a href="">Item 4</a>
  <a href="">Item 5</a>
  <a href="">Item 6</a>
</nav>
```